# unable to search using timestamp in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

I have created a timestamp field in mysql, where the date gets stored as `06/01/2010 07:55:40`

Now if I try to search anything using a query like this :

```
select StartTime 
  from results 
 where timestamp(StartTime) = "30/09/2009"
```

it does not work.

even I cannot use this :

```
select * 
  from results 
  where StartTime between "06/01/2010 07:55:40" and "01/02/2010 07:55:40"
```

If I use:

```
select  timestamp(current_date());
```

...then it shows `02/03/2010 00:00:00`

Should I change the format to something like 00-00-0000 ?  Or can I search using the same format that is currently in the table?

Can anyone suggest please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use explicit format:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    results
WHERE   starttime = TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('02/03/2010 21:30:00', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s'));
```

Comment: insted of using this everytime, will it be easy to convert my timestamp in my database?